# How to operate gas starter fireplace?

Tags: safety, gas, fireplace, metal, fire-hazard

I recently bought a house and have no idea anything about fireplaces. I would love to use my fireplace but I want to make sure I know what I am doing. I understand this is wood type fireplace and the material is metal. This might be a silly question but once I fire this guy wouldn't it gas pipe explode or something?

Is that just a gas starter? then I turn it off or keep it on? I don't know how to be safe with that gas pipe and fire going on. 
With those leftover ashes wouldn't it block the gas starter holes?
Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the valve on every one of these I've seen is outside of the firebox. Any pipe beyond the valve is going to be empty of flammable gas in a short time.

The idea behind these devices is that they replace newspaper and kindling (or however you start your wood fire) with a small gas flame. You turn it on until the fire is going  then turn it off.

You don't have to use this, you can start your fires the more traditional way and ignore this device.

If you are going to use the gas starter, you'll need to keep the firebox fairly neat and tidy to avoid burying the starter burner.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! Before I start this gas starter the first time do I have to do anything special? Cleaning etc. obviously I will clean the ashes

Comment: The gas pipe has only one hole, is this normal?

Comment: I had one years ago and I don't recall what it looked like. One jet pointed towards the middle of the wood should be sufficient, though.